# Don't work PageListener in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want set PageListener for ViewPager, but my code dont worked.

this is my code

Class for listen:

```
private class PageListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = position;
        if (currentPage == 0) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).hideArcMenu();
        } else if (currentPage == 1) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).hideArcMenu();
        } else if (currentPage == 2) {
            if (DatabaseManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllHistoryCardsCountById(((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).getCarId()) <= 0) {
                ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).showArcMenu();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and set to ViewPager:

```
vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageListener());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) 
     {
        currentPage = position;
        if (currentPage == 0) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).hideArcMenu();
        } else if (currentPage == 1) {
            ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).hideArcMenu();
        } else if (currentPage == 2) {
            if (DatabaseManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllHistoryCardsCountById(((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).getCarId()) <= 0) {
                ((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).showArcMenu();
            }
        }     
     }
     @Override
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
     {
     }
     @Override
     public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
     {
     }
});
```

Comment: (( no, this dont help me.

Comment: А этот коммент не все поймут, местные) Спасибо, выручил. Правда у меня PagerSlidingTabStrip - и в него сеттю ViewPager, а он ему этот слушатель ставит свой - и нужно через pagerTabStrip.setViewPager(vpPager);
        pagerTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {.... сеттить. Вот так вот.

Comment: Да не за что) Надеюсь, всё заработает у тебя. Тут не приветствуют чат в комментах, закругляемся)))